# MapReduce job can't talk with Hbase on a Kerberos enabled CDH cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, kerberos, cloudera-cdh

I am writing a MapReduce application to access Hbase data on a CDH cluster with Kerberos enabled. My CDH version is 5.9.0, running on 3 nodes and Kerberos version is 1.10.1. Now, I face an issue and hope someone can help.

My code:

```
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "Kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("jj@example.com", "jj.keytab");

HTable table = new HTable(conf, "myTable");
 Put p = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("myLittleRow"));
 p.add(Bytes.toBytes("myColumnFamily"), Bytes.toBytes("someQualifier"),
         Bytes.toBytes("Some Value"));
 table.put(p);
```

The above code help me to run in **local mode successfully** with `java -jar` or `hadoop -jar`. But when I try to run with a **Oozie Workflow via Hue**, the following issue happen:

```
FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'. javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
```

So, I try to use init credentials to obtain valid token to run the job via

```
TableMapReduceUtil.initCredentialsForCluster(job,conf);
```

but the issue still happen. Do someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. It's easy to configure a Hue-Ozzie job on CDH to talk with a secure Hbase.

All you need to do is:

- Enable Hbase credentials when setting up the Workflow
- Add `hbase-site.xml` to the `job.xml` path

Answer (score 0):

Although the Oozie documentation is an ugly mess, it *does* cover HBase Kerberos authentication:
https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.2.0/DG_ActionAuthentication.html

> ...some actions require talking to external services (e.g. HCatalog,
>   HBase Region Server, Hive Server 2) and in these cases, the actions
>   require some **extra configuration in Oozie to authenticate**.

Unfortunately that page has no actionable info after that. You have to revert to a good old Google search to find some useful posts, like this one:
https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/49407/how-to-set-up-oozie-to-connect-to-secured-hbase-cl-1.html

As for how the Hue UI supports that feature... honestly, I tried this lousy piece of shoftware a couple of days in 2014, then I switched to a text editor for crafting the XML scripts directly. Too many limitations in Hue.

---

Otherwise, you can resort to **explicit Kerberos auth in your Java code**, using Hadoop `UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab()` with a keytab file *(which must be downloaded via the standard `<file>` instruction in your Oozie action)*.

Comment: Finally, i found the solution with some setup on Hue CDH.   Anw, thank for reply Simson!